# iptables: force reconnections of existing connection allow new connections

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to implement a transparent http proxy using iptables. The following rule redirects traffic from port 80 to 8080 (the port the proxy is listening to)

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This works. The problem I have is that it only works for new connections. Therefore, I'm trying to force existing connections to reconnect and once connected, allow the traffic. In order to differentiate new connections from existing connections I plan to use a mark.

I'm trying the following set of rules:

```
1 iptables -A INPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
2 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 8
3 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
4 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
5 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m mark ! --mark 8 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

The intention of rules is the following:

1. Restores any mark for existing connection
2. Marks new connections
3. Saves mark for new connection
4. Accepts new connection
5. Rejects existing connections if they are not marked

However, this set of rules results in the rejection of all new or existing connections. If I invert the rule for rejecting marked packages, then all existing and new connections are accepted. Therefore, my guess is that the packages are not being marked for new connections as I would expect.

```
5 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m mark --mark 8 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

> Note: Even when documentation states that `The CONNMARK target is available in all chains and all tables`, for rules 1-4 I've also tries using `-A PREROUTING -t mangle` (as I've seen in many exaples) with the same result.

Comment: In general: evaluating firewall rules in isolation is difficult, as their context and ordering matters. Also: a typical mistake is that new rules get appended when you use `-A` and often you need new rules to get priority over (the last of the old) existing rules and the new ones should be added with `-I`

Comment: Good points. In this particular case the only rules in place are those in the question and are in the order they are listed.

Answer (score 0):

In a stateful netfilter (iptables) firewall you flush the connection tracking cache with [`[sudo] conntrack --flush`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html) which will remove all state and information about established connections.

Comment: Not sure how this is related to the question. I don't want to flush the state but to force the connections to be closed.